# How to render ealier over later child of a Row or Column in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

### Demonstration

[image: animation]

### Explanation

Imagine a *`Widget` tree* with *either* a horizontal (referring to the `direction` parameter) `Dismissible` in a `Row` *or* a vertical `Dismissible`  in a `Column`.

The [`Dismissible`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Dismissible-class.html), in both cases, is being surrounded by two other `Widget`'s.

Here are both cases:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    WillAppearBelowDismissibleThatIsBeingSwipedToTheLeft(),
    Dismissible(
      direction: DismissDirection.horizontal, child...),
    WillAppearAboveDismissibleThatIsBeingSwipedToTheRight(),
  ],)
// other case
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    WillAppearBelowDismissibleThatIsBeingSwipedUpwards(),
    Dismissible(
      direction: DismissDirection.vertical, child...),
    WillAppearAboveDismissibleThatIsBeingSwipedDownwards(),
  ],)
```

As you might be able to understand, in one of the directions the `Dismissible` will be swiped towards, it will **cover up** the `Widgets`, but **not in the other**.

How do I render the child of my `Dismissible` below **all** `Widget`'s in a `Row` or `Column` *and **vise versa***?

In the *title* I talk about *"later"* and *"earlier"*. By that I mean the order they appear in the `List` because the later they appear in it, the higher they will be rendered. I think that this can easily be observed from my demonstration because *one circle* is covered up by the `Dismissible`, but not the other.

I want to achieve the **same behavior for both** red circles.

*Code to try*:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Dismissible(
              key: ObjectKey(0),
              direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
              child: Container(
                height: 150.0,
                width: 150.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more tinkering I got a satisfying result. I used a `Stack`, but **only** removed the `Dismissible` from my `Row`.

For my example code from my question it looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.redAccent,
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.redAccent,
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Dismissible(
                    key: ObjectKey(0),
                    direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 150.0,
                      width: 150.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

In essence, I surrounded everything with a `Stack`, replaced the `Dismissible` *in the `Row`* by another `Expanded` and then placed the `Dismissible` in the `Stack` inside a `Center`.

Comment: Nice to know you are satisfied. Finally you have to use Stack. Honestly, I don’t think is a better solution. Congratulations!

Comment: @PhucTran Sorry, I cannot quite follow you. What do you mean by saying "Finally" and also "better solution" than what other solution?

Comment: No worry. I thought you only want to use Column/Row as what you commented on my answer. You also said that my solution above is not a nice solution. That may be true, but your solution is not better due to the way you nest widgets. That’s my opinion only. Anyway, you should use what make you satisfied. Thanks!

Comment: The reason I did not find your solution to be nice is that I could not get it to work for my case. I think with some more nesting in the `Positioned` Widget's it would have worked somehow, but that was really complicated for me. I think the fact that I am using `Expanded` even before that is the reason why I prefer my solution for the problem.

Comment: It’s Ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the power of Stack widget and Positioned widget to achieve what you want :)

In below example, the Dismissible is above 2 other widgets:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Layout',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: DismissibleDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class DismissibleDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Positioned(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                ),
                left: 0.0,
                top: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2) - 50),
            new Positioned(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                ),
                height: 100.0,
                width: 100.0,
                right: 0.0,
                top: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2) - 50),
            new Positioned(
              child: Dismissible(
                key: ObjectKey(0),
                direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
                child: Container(
                  height: 120.0,
                  width: 120.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              left: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) - 60,
              top: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2) - 60,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This approach completely diminishes what I needed from `Row`/`Column`. My example code is a very simple case, but I am unable to implement this into a slighty more complicated/flexible tree :( In short, I am kind of dependent on the positioning and sizing of `Row`/`Column` and only want to change the render order of one specific item.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Each widget has its use cases. How complicated/flexible tree do you have? :)

Comment: I will just try to adjust it in my `Stack` a bit more, but it is definitely not a nice solution.

Comment: OK. Please share me your nice solution with Row/Column. Thanks

Comment: Would be very happy to find one, hence I asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the direction of columns or rows:
this will render in the direction you pass in. Remember you may need to reorder the widget array tho..

```
Column(
      verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up, //Override render direction
      children: [
        myWidgetB,
        myWidgetA,
      ],
    );
```

Comment: This is true, but it does not help in this case because then you have the same problem, just in reverse :)